# Making calls through the smartphone using the PC

Tags: phone, smartphone

Is it possible to connect a smartphone through a USB cable to an Ubuntu machine and make or receive phone calls to or from other phones using the desktop?

EDIT: This is not a VOIP based question. What I intend to ask is whether, making phone calls using the GSM / 3G network is possible.

Comment: how it is related to ubuntu?

Comment: This isn't exactly ubuntu-focused, unless you want to use Ubuntu to do this, in which case, could you make that a little more clear?

Comment: I want this happening on an Ubuntu machine.

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/questions/768121/make-and-receive-calls-on-ubuntu-using-an-external-android-phone

Comment: I just placed a successfull voice call using https://github.com/sehari24jam/python-gsmmodem

Answer (score 5):

I think I understand what you mean. I've got Ubuntu 12.10 and by instaling **AirDroid**, you can access and control your mobile phone from your desktop.

There are two modes:

- One using a central site where you conect and.. bla bla, we guys don't care... but works ok!!
- The other one is by using mobile phone IP granted by your Wi Fi network, open web broswser on PC and type **http://*phoneIPaddress*:8888**  This way your browser will handle the phone... voila

Installing

1. To install AirDroid go to GooglePlay, install it to your android
   device,
2. Run it from your device and copy the **IP** showed on your
   screen
3. On your desktop web browser, type:

   http://**IP**:8888
   This will open the android screen, that is all.

I recomend using bluetooth headseat for phone calls, this way the PC initiate the call the rest is between the phone and the bluetooth headset.  Got one from amazon for less than U$5 and headset cost me around U$30, the more expensive headset were really disappointing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: okey so i made i phone call from my computer, but the audio is not transfered to my computer headphones. how do i setup the airdroid to transfer the audio from phone call to my pc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The smartphone just provides an IP connection to and from the web (and some carriers, like Virgin Mobile USA, block VOIP traffic- be warned).

1. If you have a Google account you can add [Google Voice](https://support.google.com/voice/?hl=en#topic=1707989) for free, dial
   in the Chrome or Chromium browsers with Google Voice (free in the US
   et Canada) and then use the microphone and speaker of your machine.
   There was an extension for Firefox years ago, but no longer. [Here's a review](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/google-in-the-enterprise/see-whats-new-with-google-voice/) and a [critique](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-build-your-own-more-powerful-version-of-google-575896480). Been using it since 2007 and it works reliably, with no commercials, even though free.
2. You can also add a [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) client like [Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/) or [SFLphone](http://sflphone.org/) among [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_software#Free_and_open_source_license_2) and use VOIP providers such as [CallCentric](http://www.callcentric.com/). You get what you pay for with VOIP providers, but I've been happy with CallCentric. Here are [two](http://www.dslreports.com/comments/3050), count them two, [reviews](http://www.voipreview.org/reviews/callcentric).

Comment: I did not ask a VOIP based question. I just want to connect my PC to the cellphone network and dial a call. Like a modem does.