# Make and receive calls on Ubuntu using an external android phone

Tags: 16.04, android, phone, sms

Is there any way that I could use my old Android device by connecting it via USB or even using the wireless LAN and make/receive calls and traditional text messages (SMS) on my laptop running Ubuntu?

Comment: you need to install a VoIP program and you would be best to just do a search on that .. way too much information to try to deal with on a forum like this ... your best bet would be to look into VoIP and if you have  problems with installing or configuring a program then come back and ask ... this is just too broad of a subject and lets just say its not going to be a quick easy task to accomplish

Comment: you will probably have to set up servers and clients so its going to be complicated You may even need special equipment... I know its possible because basically that is what MagicJack is but as for how to accomplish it .. I'm at a loss there

Comment: YATE is the simplest solution to outgoing calls and texts I've found so far. I've used it to call long distance numbers without charge. Incoming is another issue requiring the caller to have YATE, Jabber or your gmail address to contact you.

Answer (score 0):

[This topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151524/is-there-any-way-to-use-ubuntu-with-an-android-phone) looks to be asking the same or a similar question, and the answer cites Android Notifier (linked in that thread) as a potential solution.

I don't know if you've considered it, or if it would be an appropriate response (if not, please edit or remove as necessary!)... But Google Voice allows for a new phone number which is used over WiFi. I have previously used that service for a business phone line as a Web developer, so that I could give a local number to clients and retain the privacy of my personal cell phone.

This does not rely on the phone being plugged into the computer, though, so perhaps this answer is not correct because it does not technically "use Ubuntu;" however, Google Voice can be used on the Web browser in Ubuntu (or any OS), as well as on your phone. You could download the app via WiFi on your old Android device and use it that way.

Forgive me if this is an irrelevant response, but if nothing else, a valid alternative.

Comment: It's definitely a valid alternative but that's not my objective. I'm looking at some way to 'dock' my phone to Ubuntu and be able to use actual cellular functions off my laptop rather than the phone.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you managed to achieve what you wanted but if not a possible solution that I use is the app AirDroid.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. On top of that the exact same thing is suggested by another answer here. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you answer calls from your Ubuntu laptop, but for SMS, you could use KDEConnect (despite the name, it will work on Unity according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/951622/957314)). Follow the instructions posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/951622/957314) to install KDEConnect on your laptop, and then install KDEConnect on your phone via [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.kde.kdeconnect_tp/) or [the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp&hl=en_US). Then, make sure the devices are connected to the same network, open up KDEConnect on your laptop and phone and click on your phone's name. Finally, choose your desired settings and click "Pair". Now, you can use SMS from your laptop, wirelessly share files between your devices, and sync notifications, among other things.