# Is there a way to answer phone calls from my ubuntu 20?

Tags: 20.04, android

Microsoft windows has an app called your phone which integrates your android phone and pc and allows us to view photos,screenshots,notifications,sms and answer calls.
Since many months,I have been searching for a similar app for ubuntu but I am unable to find such thing.I used things like kde connect but it does not allow me to answer calls.

Comment: Get a Skype number for your country.

Comment: how about https://askubuntu.com/questions/16305/how-can-i-make-usual-phone-calls-using-a-connected-mobile-phone ?

Comment: @Rinzwind https://github.com/heinervdm/nohands/issues/6

Comment: Did you have a chance of testing anything of what was suggested?

Answer (score 6):

There is no such Linux or Ubuntu application at this time to link your Android phone or tablet to a Linux computer to handle calls, texts, notifications, etc.  Samsung had initially experimented with a Linux variant of their DeX integration, but abandoned it to be windows only.

There is no way to do that interception on Linux, but if you connect your phone to Linux you can use `scrcpy` to 'mirror' your screen onto your Linux system, thereby 'controlling' the Android device for texts, etc. however that all requires local connectivity and is entirely still run 'on the phone' rather than offloading/linking to the Linux environment - this also means calls, etc. still have to be handled on that phone.

---

One possibility *might* be [GSConnect](https://github.com/GSConnect/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/wiki), which is an implementation of KDE Connect as a GNOME extension, *might* work, but I haven't heard any positive feedback from anyone on whether it works without root.

It supposedly works with the KDE Connect application on the Android side, however it has a requisite of being on the same wifi network as your other device running it (Bluetooth is not an option for pairing in the KDE Connect app on the Android side).  There may also be firewall restrictions if you run a firewall on your machine, but I haven't fully tested this to see if this is a solution to actually route and handle calls, etc. from your Android device to a computer.

Comment: any possibility of gsconnect supporting this feature by enabling bluetooth connection?

Comment: @nazar2sfive Possibly, but the KDE Connect application on Android only seems to support wifi, not BT.

Comment: I hope somebody makes this working via KDE connect/GSconnect. https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436867 https://github.com/GSConnect/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/issues/668 Just posting here to raise this issue.

Comment: `sudo apt install kdeconnect` will install vanilla kde connect. Is GSConnect any different feature-wise? KDE Connect is  a great package; I dont really like how installs as 4 different GUI apps. Having 4 identical icons in the apps menu is a bit of a putoff, but it is still worth the $0.00. Btw, Kde connect runs via wifi and bluetooth. If you do not believe me, pair your device and pc /laptop, and then turn your device's bluetooth off. (consolidated comments.)

Comment: I also want to mention a couple more options, which are at (or just over) the edge of OP's requirements scope. The first is ADB, which has no gui, but if you know how to use it, It can access & use a device in any way that the mentioned apps can and more.. I doubt you'll want to make phone calls via command line, but if that is your thing... Ive texted via terminal when debugging Android software, so I know it is (or at least it was) possible. The other app is Heimdall. It is nothing like the others, but is a must for some Android users. It's Windows counterpart is Odin.

Comment: @ThomasWard **HFP for Linux.** https://github.com/heinervdm/nohands/issues/6

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~sebastian-ruehl/+archive/ubuntu/nohands

Comment: @NateT the *main application* for KDE Connect does, the actual application that you have to install on the **mobile devices** does not.  It only works on Wifi on android.

Comment: @nazar2sfive That allows you to use your computer as a speaker/microphone, but it does not solve the remaining things that are indicated by OP, handling the call accepts, notifications, etc. like the Windows apps for Samsung and Android can do.

Comment: @ThomasWard yea my bad, I had it backward; device bluetooth needs to be off for mine to work for me (think its because they autoconnect via bluetooth. Must not be able to attain both pairings - KDE & BT - simustaneously.) I was probably turning it on when I thought I was turning it off.

Comment: Correction. They will pair regardless of bt, The phone will just display a 'connected device unreachable ' error until I toggle bluetooth off.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting here **a complete solution** for the two-fold problem you are posing:

1. Connect audio from Android to Ubuntu.
2. Control your Android device, including phone calls from Ubuntu.

### Connect audio

This is somewhat straightforward via bluetooth.
If you don't have a bluetooth adapter, you can purchase a dongle, which is quite cheap.

Follow these steps:

1. Install the following packages if needed (you most likely have them)

   ```
    $ sudo apt install pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils pavucontrol pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
   ```
2. Pair your phone with your Ubuntu.
3. It might be working right away. If not, edit `~/.config/pulse/system.pa` to add

   ```
    .include /etc/pulse/system.pa
    load-module module-bluetooth-policy
    load-module module-bluetooth-discover
   ```

   and execute

   ```
    $ sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
   ```

   If this doesn't work, try rebooting.
4. If this doesn't work yet, add to `~/.config/pulse/system.pa` the following line:

   ```
    load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
   ```

   and reboot.

**Sources**:

1. https://ostechnix.com/turn-your-linux-pc-into-bluetooth-speakers-for-your-phone/

### Control the android device from Ubuntu

AirDorid can be used to control quite a few features in an Android phone, including File transfer, SMSs, etc.
I did not try it myself, but I read various sources stating that **this includes handling phone calls**. YMMV.
Using the sound devices of your Ubuntu is described above.
**In this sense, it could be a better option than GSConnect/KDEConnect**.

To use AirDroid:

1. Install AirDroid in your phone and launch it.
2. Set an IP <x.x.x.x> in your phone, for accessing in a web browser.
3. Visit http://x.x.x.x:8888 in your Ubuntu web browser.

**Sources**:

1. [Making calls through the smartphone using the PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392618/making-calls-through-the-smartphone-using-the-pc)
2. https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2012/02/airdroid-access-your-android-phone-from.html
3. https://www.maketecheasier.com/airdroid-connect-android-phone-to-linux/